# Finding record using LINQ WCF Ado.net "Does not match return type"

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, visual-studio-2012, wcf-data-services

I am trying to search for a record using the ID.
I have code that returns all records successfully however I am unsure how to return just one matching record.

I am using C#, linq, WCF & ADO.net Data services. I apologise if this is a dupe, could somebody please explain where I am going wrong. I am inexperienced with this language.

```
public List<Vehicle> SearchVehicleRecord(int vehicleID)
        {

            VehicleStockItem vehicle =
                (from v in db.VehicleStockItems
                 where v.VehicleStockItemID == vehicleID
                 select v
                 ).First();
            return vehicle;
        }
```

The error I receive is "Error   1   'VehicleSalesService.Service1' does not implement interface member 'VehicleSalesService.IService1.SearchVehicleRecord(int)'. 'VehicleSalesService.Service1.SearchVehicleRecord(int)' cannot implement 'VehicleSalesService.IService1.SearchVehicleRecord(int)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. C:\Users\Dale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\VehicleSalesService\VehicleSalesService\Service1.cs 12  18  VehicleSalesService"

"Error  2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'VehicleSalesService.Models.VehicleStockItem' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'  C:\Users\Dale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\VehicleSalesService\VehicleSalesService\Service1.cs 64  20  VehicleSalesService"

This is the operation

```
    [OperationContract]
    List<Vehicle> SearchVehicleRecord(int vehicleID);
```

This is the definition of VehicleStockItem

```
public partial class VehicleStockItem
    {
        public int VehicleStockItemID { get; set; }
        public int ColourID { get; set; }
        public int VehicleTypeID { get; set; }
        public int WheelTypeID { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Registration { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Capacity { get; set; }
        public bool Automatic { get; set; }
        public bool Sold { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime StockEntryDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateNew { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public virtual Colour Colour { get; set; }
        public virtual VehicleType VehicleType { get; set; }
        public virtual WheelType WheelType { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a single instance of `VehicleStockItem` in your method implementation.

Your method signature says you are returning a `List<Vehicle>` collection.

You can overload your method so you have one implementation that returns a single record when you pass an id in and one method that returns a collection based on any parameters passed in.

Depending on if you are adding or replacing your existing method, you'd add or update your contract

```
 [OperationContract]
 VehicleStockItem SearchVehicleRecord(int vehicleID);
```

Then you'd update your signature to match your contract:

```
  public VehicleStockItem SearchVehicleRecord(int vehicleID)
    {

        VehicleStockItem vehicle =
            (from v in db.VehicleStockItems
             where v.VehicleStockItemID == vehicleID
             select v
             ).First();
        return vehicle;
    }
```

Comment: is it possible for you to provide an example, thanks. I wish to return only one record.

Comment: The new contract now says it cant find the type or namespace VehicleStockItem. When I add "Using VehicleSalesService.models" it removes the error but when I invoke the service it returns an error saying the sequence contains no elements.

Comment: Your code is crashing because there is no data being returned by the query and using `First()` expects data in the sequence  (your query). If you are expecting that sometimes no results are returned, use `FirstOrDefault()` which will return `null` when there are no results.

Comment: When I return a record that I know is definitely in there I get the following error: http://s28.postimg.org/i67o5aowt/error_WCF.jpg I find this odd because I can run the code to get all records but not this. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you create the method SearchVehicleRecord(int vehicleID) you have stated that it will return a LIST of Vehicles.

However, in your linq query, when you call .First() you are picking out a SINGLE vehicle and storing it in your VehicleStockItem vehicle. Then you return that single VehicleStockItem object when what the method needs you to return is a LIST of Vehicles.

So really, there are two problems: You define the method to return a List of Vehicles, but actually return neither a list NOR a vehicle, but rather a single VehicleStockItem. (It says return vehicle, but that's just your particular name of the VehicleStockItem type object you created.)

Try changing your method signature to

```
   public VehicleStockItem SearchVehicleRecord(int vehicleID)
    {

        VehicleStockItem vehicle =
            (from v in db.VehicleStockItems
             where v.VehicleStockItemID == vehicleID
             select v
             ).First();
        return vehicle;
    }
```

This expects a single VehicleStockItem returned, which is what you give it.

Comment: And what about the operation contract? What must this be changed to?

Comment: Well, I am also somewhat of a beginner as well, and am less familiar with operation contracts, but at the very least, since there doesn't appear to be a Vehicle object defined anywhere, you can't really have a list of them. I'd suggest changing that to VehicleStockItem as well. Singular. Is there any case in which you will want to be passing multiple vehicleid's in and storing up results in a list?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the method:

```
public List<Vehicle> SearchVehicleRecord(int vehicleID)
        {

            VehicleStockItem vehicle =
                (from v in db.VehicleStockItems
                 where v.VehicleStockItemID == vehicleID
                 select v
                 ).First();
            return vehicle;
        }
```

What are the problems:

- having a return type, but returning something of a different type
- returning a `VehicleStockItem`, but expecting a `List` as return

Maybe you should modify your method, to be like this:

```
public VehicleStockItem SearchVehicleRecord(int vehicleID)
        {

            VehicleStockItem vehicle =
                (from v in db.VehicleStockItems
                 where v.VehicleStockItemID == vehicleID
                 select v
                 ).First();
            return vehicle;
        }
```

If you do this, make sure you follow it with your `OperationContract` and where you define the `OperationContract`, `VehicleStockItem` is defined.

You might modify your method to return a list with the single element you want.

Or, you can convert `vehicle` to be `Vehicle` and modify the `OperationContract` to expect a `Vehicle` result instead of a `List` of `Vehicle` elements.

Comment: Hi @LajosArpad VehicleStockItem is defined automatically in models. Right now I have it set up as you suggested with the operation contract as follows:
[OperationContract]
VehicleStockItem SearchVehicleRecord(int vehicleID);     .... When I invoke the the service it gives an error and says "Sequence has no elements" as if it didn't find any records?

Comment: It seems that you need to use a list there then. In that case, you can create a list with a single element to work-around the problem.